# Webpack not found when deploying using heroku

Tags: heroku, webpack, deployment

I'm trying to deploy an app on heroku, but I'm getting an error when it tried to build the app with the webpack command. I have tried a number of fixes but can't seem to get it to work. I tried running the webpack.js file from node_modules like this `node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js` but that didn't work either. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated! Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "waste-not-client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "concurrently npm:watch:*",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "watch:compile": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "watch:serve": "nodemon server/server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install && npm run build && node server/server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Blue-ocean-HR/blueocean-client.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Blue-ocean-HR/blueocean-client/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.12.0",
    "axios": "^1.1.3",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "framer-motion": "^7.6.7",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-autocomplete-input": "^1.0.19",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "babel-jest": "^29.1.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.1",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^10.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^8.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.19",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^7.8.3",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "v16.16.0"
  }
}
```

The error when I try to deploy on heroku:

```
sh: 1: webpack: not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `start` script looks like it's designed for development work with live reloading. That's not what you want on Heroku.

You could rewrite your `package.json` scripts, but the easiest solution is probably to add a `Procfile` that Heroku will use in preference to your `start` script, e.g.

```
web: node server/server.js
```

You'll also want to remove your `heroku-postbuild` script entirely. It just repeats two things that Heroku does automatically (installing dependencies and running your build), and it also includes the runtime command that we now have in our `Procfile`.

Comment: @maximosis, ah. I believe you'll want to remove that `heroku-postbuild` script altogether. Heroku installs dependencies and runs your build automatically at build time.

Comment: Ah that worked thanks Chris! I have a new issue now, the site is only displaying the index.html file and none of my react code is rendering. Any ideas on why that might happen?

Comment: The React issue is a separate issue. Nothing in the question above even mentions React. Please search for existing questions and, if necessary, ask a new question.